# One row in database vs multiple column's data need to display as pie chart

Tags: php, html, sql

I have only one row in database with many columns, each column has different value. I need to display this information in the form of pie chart on a PHP web page.

In all the tutorials, multiple row Vs single column data is displayed.

Please help

Note: Data on the pie chart should be picked from data base.

Comment: Its easy to do with jpgraph.Hope this will be work for you http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_pie1.php

Comment: transpose the row, so you will have multiple rows.

Comment: @Chonchol Mahmud: Data to be picked from PHP Database please.

Comment: @raj query the data from your database and put it into `$data` variable as an `array`.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud : where to find these
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_pie.php');

Im getting below error

Warning: require_once(jpgraph/jpgraph.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'jpgraph/jpgraph.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: download the script from http://jpgraph.net/download/

Answer (score 0):

Following are two options, one paid and the other one free.

chartlogix (paid)
populate the related fields with data from your columns.

```
<?
include( 'chartlogix.inc.php' );

$pie = new PieChart();

$pie->setTitle( "ChartLogix Pie Chart" );

$pie->addData( 'column 1', <data from column 1>, 'FFCC00' );
$pie->addData( 'column 2', <data from column 2>, '99FF00' );
$pie->addData( 'column 3', <data from column 3>, 'FF6666' );
$pie->addData( 'column 4', <data from column 4>, '009900' );
$pie->addData( 'column 5', <data from column 5>, '9900CC' );
$pie->addData( 'column 6', <data from column 6>, 'AAAAAA' );

$pie->drawPNG( 500, 400 );
?>
```

pChart  (Free)
populate "series1" with column name and "series2" with data from columns.

```
 // Standard inclusions     
include("pChart/pData.class");  
include("pChart/pChart.class");  

// Dataset definition   
$DataSet = new pData;  
$DataSet->AddPoint(array(10,2,3,5,3),"Serie1");  
$DataSet->AddPoint(array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May"),"Serie2");  
$DataSet->AddAllSeries();  
$DataSet->SetAbsciseLabelSerie("Serie2");  

// Initialise the graph  
$Test = new pChart(300,200);  
$Test->loadColorPalette("Sample/softtones.txt");  
$Test->drawFilledRoundedRectangle(7,7,293,193,5,240,240,240);  
$Test->drawRoundedRectangle(5,5,295,195,5,230,230,230);  

// This will draw a shadow under the pie chart  
$Test->drawFilledCircle(122,102,70,200,200,200);  

// Draw the pie chart  
$Test->setFontProperties("Fonts/tahoma.ttf",8);  
    $Test->drawBasicPieGraph($DataSet->GetData(),$DataSet->GetDataDescription(),120,100,70,PIE_PERCENTAGE,255,255,218);
 $Test->drawPieLegend(230,15,$DataSet->GetData(),$DataSet->GetDataDescription(),250,250,250);  

 $Test->Render("example14.png");  
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any working model?
How to get pChart/pData.class, pChart/pChart.class

Comment: Get the php files from their respective websites (any one) and include them in your code as shown above. Then fetch the data from database using select query and populate the fields in above code with your data.

Comment: I asking about include("pChart/pData.class");  
include("pChart/pChart.class");

Comment: I never used it myself but if you download the plugin i guess thats the directory/ file structure that you will get.